# Check via Google API that particular e-mail is a member of particular Google group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-workspace

I have G Suite for my domain, and I have a Google group in this G Suite whose members could be domain users or external e-mail addresses.

I need to check via Google API that particular address is a member of this group.

I found the following two methods: [hasMember](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/hasMember) and [list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list), however neither of them is good for my purpose.  The former method seems to work with domain users only, so if I pass external email as `memberKey` parameter to this method, it just returns HTTP status code `400` and response looking like this:

```js
{
  "error": {
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "required",
      "message": "Missing required field: memberKey"
    }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Missing required field: memberKey"
}
```

When I pass email that is in my domain, I get HTTP code `200` and response looking like this:

```js
{
  "isMember": false
}
```

The latter method returns me all the addresses within the group, including external ones, but it does not scale to really large groups.

Are there any other methods (or other ways to use these methods) that I could use to solve my problem?

Comment: Error 400 means Bad Request - as in your request is not formatted correctly or has invalid fields/data. Are you sure that the returned error is `400 Not Found`? Double check how you are specifying the `memberKey`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Code is `400`, but message is different.  My mistake, will fix the original answer.

Comment: 1) Show the code with an example that works another that fails. Change the emails to hide the real identity. 2) Are you correctly encoding the URL params? The answer might be in your code.

Comment: Not sure what code you need, as I didn't yet decide what Google API function to use.  Among two promising candidates one seems to not do what I need and another does not scale.  The problem with `hasMember` is reproducible in Google API explorer without any code at all.

Comment: You must have code that is generating the error. the first step is to create working code (prototype). Then you worry about scaling. At this point, I cannot help further.

Comment: Code that is generating error would not count as working prototype, and working prototype will not generate errors.  I can create working prototype using `list` method, but on really large groups it will break.  See no reason to use `hasMember` in code while I cannot make it work properly even in API Explorer.